# How this final StringBuffer value gets modified after created in java?

Tags: java, oop, final

I know final variable characteristics.It can't be changed from its initialized state.But
When using the `final` variable in `StringBuffer` class then the Object of the `StringBuffer` class will get modified using `append()` method in java.

How `StringBuffer` differs from others with respect to using with final modifier...

Please guide me to get out clear idea about this...

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder.  It was replaced nine years ago and wasn't a good idea in the first place IMHO.

Comment: Final is for not instantiating object again, not for modifying its attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`final` means in this case: that the reference to the object is final (it can only be assigned once), not the object itself.

The object itself can still be modified.

Answer (score 12):

`final` only says the variable cannot be reassigned. but the attributes of the variable can still be changed

Answer (score 5):

A common mistake is to assume that `sb` in the following example is an object.

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

In fact `sb` is a reference. It is 4 bytes (or possibly 8 bytes) no matter what object it refers to. That reference cannot change.  However the object referenced can change.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `final` reference to `StringBuffer` then it means that the reference cannot be re-assigned but you can always update the object that this reference is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

you question is more appropriate with array objects.

```
final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
```

Here `sb` is final you can not overrite sb reference value but the Object associated with sb, that have certain characteristics those will not change and this is one of that.

Answer (score 0):

The `final` keyword in Java is means that the variable referencing the object can't be reassigned. But that doesn't mean that the object himself cannot change its state.

Answer (score 0):

> you have made it "final" not "immutable".... final means you cant
>   reassign the reference and make it point to some other object (in this
>   context)... The value of the object to which you point can change.
>
> For example : Assume you have a reference to a car object. You can
>   change the properties of the car (color, sound system, seats etc...)
>   but not the car to which you are pointing..
>
> To prevent any changes in attributes of the object, you have to make
>   it "immutable". Which can be done by making the setters of an object private or other means...
>
> Hope this makes sense..